# Pass value from executing script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to pass the value from an executing script to another file. Capture.py is the executing script. The script is running and will end only when KeyboardInterrupt.

```
#capture.py
def default(interface):
    """ Capture packets """
    for ts, pkt in pcap.pcap(interface):
        return ts, pkt

while True:
    return default(interface)
```

I want another script that can get the value of ts, pkt when executed. And while terminating this script, the capture.py needs to be still running.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to think about saving what you are trying to return into a file or if, as I suspect, this is a scapy script then you need to make use of callbacks.